# How do I override the not found page in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I have a CodeIgniter application that's generally working how I'd like it to, but occasionally a user will go to a page that does not exist and is greeted with an unfriendly error. I'd like to detect the error automatically and display useful information to the user (not PHP errors). I read the user guide of CodeIgniter, but I couldn't find any relevant section.

How do I handle a page-not-found error in CodeIgniter and display my own custom content?

Comment: This text does not reflect the askers question. The asker is asking about 404 pages. See this comments below.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at handling errors with your own custom page, you can modify the error templates found in `application/errors`.  If you have a reason to based on your own code, you can manually send the user to one of these pages using `show_404` or `show_error` - check out the [Error Handling](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) page in the official docs.

Answer (score 1):

Try these codeigniter functions

```
show_404('Your error message');
show_error('Your error message');
```

you can find more detail at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

example:

```
if ($some_error) //condition
{
 show_error('Error');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test for error return values and catch exceptions. This is a general programming concept - not something specific to Conigniter or PHP.

Testing for error return values:

```
if (!sort($array))
{
    echo "Could not sort $array.";
}
```

Catching exceptions:

```
try
{
    $someFunction($data);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
```

Of course write useful error messages with pertinent info that helps the user find their problem, and/or helps you fix your bug. You could get advanced and use something like set_error_handler():
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

I found this interesting article:
http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/error-handling-in-codeigniter/

I'm not sure it reflects the current CI release as it's from 2007.

Comment: thank u 4 ur replay ... but all i want is when the framework detect `404 error` it automatically display a message i want??

Comment: Well, you should have asked that question then. No mention of 404 anywhere in your question. Please re-write it.

Comment: I'm not really sure that a 404 is something that you should be throwing an exception for...