# http errors handling in codeigniter framework php?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to handle error in codeigniter framework php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643182/how-to-handle-error-in-codeigniter-framework-php)

http errors handling in codeigniter framework php??

how can i do that so when anywhere it catch 404 error or else display a message i want??

Comment: You've asked the exact same question before: [how to handle error in codeigniter framework php??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643182/how-to-handle-error-in-codeigniter-framework-php). If you are unsatisfied with the answers, then work on your question quality. Reposting won't help.

Comment: Within 1 hour as well. You could've read the whole user guide in that time!

Answer (score 0):

you can always edit the files in the /application/errors folder.
That is the standard CI error message you get. You know the one with the red 1px box.